# Resizing UITextView with UIView below

Tags: ios, objective-c

I can't understand how create something like this:

[image]

The idea is the `UITextView` is resizing. But how to resize it when user enter 100 rows? I need to check /n and then increment frame by lineHeight and frame of cell?

Suggest pls.

Answer (score 0):

No need. The text view should be resized to fit the keyboard. After that it scrolls the text if there is more text than fits into the visible part.

Comment: OK. But I want to make thant when user hide keyboard he can scroll to bottom all his entered text. 
P.S. I have some other elements after my textview.

Answer (score 0):

The path of least resistance to getting what you're describing to work is to create a method that updates the frames of the UITextView and UIView when the keyboard goes up or down. You know when the keyboard goes up and down based on `UIKeyboardWillShowNotification` and `UIKeyboardWillDisappearNotification`. The notification contains a `userInfo` dictionary that specifies the y-coordinate of the keyboard with respect to your view controller's window. All you need to do is recalculate your frames subtracting the height of the keyboard (either something like 216 or 0). If you still have questions about this let me know, and I'd be happy to explain further.